# Are spaces allowed in an IRI?

Tags: java, uri, iri

I'm using Java's URI class to validate whether or not an IRI is proper.  According to the documentation, the URI can spit out an IRI string and it can likewise be constructed from an IRI string.  I have a situation where the IRI I'm given contains spaces and the URI is throwing an exception (the IRI in question is `http://My IRI Test`).

Looking at the [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3987.txt), it seems that spaces are not allowed but I would like to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces are not allowed but you can escape them: `http://My%20Iri%20Test`

You can use JAVA's [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to do that.